# ngAfterViewInit not patching the form's values

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I want to set the form's value with something that I have stored in the `localStorage`. The output of the console in the `ngAfterViewInit()` function shows a value existing for `monthlyHoursName`.
The output for the values of the form is `{}`, i.e. an empty object. I think I am missing something, but I thought `ngAfterViewInit()` was being called after the form is initialized.

```
export class MonthlyHoursComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ...
  @ViewChild('workDayHourForm') workDayHourForm: NgForm;
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.workDayHourForm.form.patchValue({
      name: localStorage.getItem('monthlyHoursName') || '',
      hours: 0,
    });
    console.log(
      'localStorage.getItem("monthlyHoursName")',
      localStorage.getItem('monthlyHoursName')
    );
    console.log(
      'this.workDayHourForm.form.getRawValue()',
      this.workDayHourForm.form.getRawValue()
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

The HTML for the component:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="monthly-form">
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-content>
        <form
          #workDayHourForm="ngForm"
          (ngSubmit)="addWorkday(workDayHourForm)"
        >
          <h2>Working Hours Tracker</h2>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <input
                  matInput
                  name="name"
                  ngModel
                  [disabled]="fixedNameMonthYear"
                />
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Month and Year</mat-label>
                <input
                  name="monthYear"
                  matInput
                  (click)="dp.open()"
                  [(ngModel)]="monthYear"
                  [matDatepicker]="dp"
                  [disabled]="fixedNameMonthYear"
                />
                <mat-datepicker-toggle
                  matIconSuffix
                  [for]="dp"
                  [disabled]="fixedNameMonthYear"
                ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker
                  #dp
                  [disabled]="fixedNameMonthYear"
                  startView="year"
                  (monthSelected)="setMonthAndYear($event, dp)"
                  panelClass="example-month-picker"
                >
                </mat-datepicker>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Day</mat-label>
                <input
                  name="dayOfMonth"
                  matInput
                  ngModel
                  type="number"
                  min="1"
                  max="31"
                />
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Hours</mat-label>
                <input
                  name="hours"
                  ngModel
                  matInput
                  type="number"
                  min="0"
                  max="400"
                />
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-btn">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
              Add To List
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
  <div class="add-list">
    <app-monthly-hour-table
      #workTable
      (workItemsChanged)="disableCheckNameMonthYear()"
    ></app-monthly-hour-table>
  </div>
  <div class="form-btn">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit List</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On which element did you put `#workDayHourForm` in template?

Comment: There is only one form in the Component's HTML.

Comment: Why can't you access FromGroup directly, without `@ViewChild`?

Comment: I thought this is the only way. How can I directly access it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `this.workDayHourForm.patchValue({...` instead of `this.workDayHourForm.form.patchValue({...`. if you are putting `#workDayHourForm` on the form element in the template.

Comment: `error TS2339: Property 'patchValue' does not exist on type 'NgForm'.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Template Driven** Form then you need to use below code for patch value

```
this.workDayHourForm.control.patchValue({
   name: localStorage.getItem('monthlyHoursName') || '',
   hours: 0,
});
```

If you are using **Reactive Form** then you need to use below code

```
this.workDayHourForm.patchValue({
   name: localStorage.getItem('monthlyHoursName') || '',
   hours: 0,
});
```

Comment: I am using template driven. But I am still getting no value.

Comment: can you please share your html code also?

Comment: Of course, added it as well.